# Rails Omniauth, set a numerical value only on first model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm using the `omniauth-facebook` gem to authenticate users on my Rails 4 website.

When a user first joins I want to give them 500 free points; but if I set that field to 500 in my model method every time a user logs in it's reset to 500 points.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.location = auth.info.location
      user.facebookpage = auth.info.urls.Facebook
      user.email = auth.extra.raw_info.email

      # This works but every time a user logs in it resets their points.
      user.points = 500 

      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

end
```

Any suggestions on how to assign 500 points only on first account creation.

Comment: Why do you have `.tap` in there? I think omniauth tutorial doesn't have it?

Answer (score 0):

That's what first_or_initialize is!

From Rails docs

```
# Find the first user named Scarlett or create a new one with a particular last name.
User.where(:first_name => 'Scarlett').first_or_create(:last_name => 'Johansson')
# => <User id: 2, first_name: 'Scarlett', last_name: 'Johansson'>

# Find the first user named Scarlett or create a new one with a different last name.
# We already have one so the existing record will be returned.
User.where(:first_name => 'Scarlett').first_or_create do |user|
  user.last_name = "O'Hara"
end
# => <User id: 2, first_name: 'Scarlett', last_name: 'Johansson'>
```

`find_or_create` is complementary to `first_or_initialize`, the former persists the object. [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)